# Why does heapsort run in $\Theta(n \log n)$ instead of $\Theta(n^2 \log n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, landau-notation, sorting

I am reading section 6.4 on Heapsort algorithm in CLRS, page 160.

```
HEAPSORT(A)  
1 BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)  
2 for i to A.length downto 2  
3   exchange A[i] with A[i]
4   A.heap-size = A.heap-size-1  
5   MAX-HEAPIFY(A,1)
```

Why is the running time, according to the book is $\Theta (n\lg{n})$ rather than $\Theta (n^2\lg{n})$ ? `BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)` takes $\Theta(n)$, `MAX-HEAPIFY(A,1)` takes $\Theta(\lg{n})$ and repeated $n-1$ times (line 3).

Comment: Where does the n^2 lg n come from? Your numbers don't add up to n^2 log n but to n lg n.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let us count operations line by line. You construct the heap in linear time. Then, you execute the loop and perform a logarithmic time operation $n-1$ times. Other operations take constant time. Hence, your running time is

$\qquad \begin{align}
& n + (n-1) \log n + O(1) \\
&= n + n \log n - \log n + O(1) \\
&= \Theta(n \log n).
\end{align}$

In other words, as $n$ grows the $n \log n$ term dominates. That is, the cost of building the heap on line 1 is negligible compared to the cost of executing the loop.

Comment: Oh, I messed up. I had in mind $n*(n-1)*\log{n}$, rather than $n + ....$ The `For` loop is $(n-1)\log{n}$ and `BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)`should have been just added. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

I had a different view altogether on this. I could not ignore the fact that in the MAX_HEAPIFY step in the sort (which has a order of $\log n$, where $n$ is the heap size) receives a diminished heap size in each iteration. So to me the Summation looked more or less like $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log k\approx \log (n!)$. Now I know that $n! =\Theta(n^n)$ that way $\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$, but it was never convincing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're not convinced about (or why you're posting an answer that you're not convinced is true).